# Tun/Tap interface based tunnel: How is it working?

Tags: linux, networking, linux-kernel

> Tun/Tap interface based tunnel

Can someone tell me how such a tunnel is created and works?

I have tried Googling the answer, but there are very few ressources and they are primarily very technical.

---

I know that packets sent through such an interface gets injected into the OS network stack and look like packets received from an external host. Also, packets received on this interface gets passed to a user-space program.

However, what I do not understand the following:

Why does such a tunnel involve the use of setting up network connections?  Is the programs on either side of the tunnel neccessarily running on the same host, or can they be running on different hosts? Does the network stack deliver tap or tun packages through TCP/UDP?

Answer (score 2):

Both Tun and Tap interfaces deliver data from one host to another. The main difference is the features (pros/cons) that you get when you are using Tun or Tap.

Data delivered via Tap interface gets injected at layer2 of OSI stack and data delivered via Tun interface gets injected and layer3. There is no better/worse choice here - each is suited for specific purpose. You can read a very good explanation [here](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/BridgingAndRouting).

Now to answer your questions:

Why does such a tunnel involve the use of setting up network connections?

You want to deliver packets from one host to another regardless the interface type (tun/tap). To do so you capture those packets, encapsulate them and then you need to send over encapsulated data to the remote end. To do this you need to set up a network connection.

Is the programs on either side of the tunnel neccessarily running on the same host, or can they be running on different hosts?

You are creating a VPN connection between two different hosts, so yes - there will be software running on both hosts which will handle the encapsulation/decapsulation.

Does the network stack deliver tap or tun packages through TCP/UDP?

TCP/UDP are layer4 protocols, so from point of view of TCP/UDP stack it does not matter at all if the packet came to your host via tun or tap interface.

EDIT: Clarification about the follow up questions:

Since you are asking about Tun/Tap adapters, let's take a step back. When you run a VPN, you have a computer A behaving as if it is directly connected to network N, even though it might be somewhere far away. To make this happen, you run a VPN software. You have to run this VPN software in two places - one in the computer A and another in computer (or network device) connected to the network N. When running a VPN software in the computer A, you have a choice of creating a Tun or Tap adapter.

Q1: Yes - delivered means sent and received.

Q2: Yes - means that VPN connection is like a pipe, and there is VPN software running at both ends.

Q3: When VPN software is running in the computer A, it creates what is called a virtual network adapter. This virtual network adapter, in the eyes of OS, behaves like a normal network adapter. Just instead of sending data over the wire or waves, it caputers the data, encapsulates it and sends over some other adapter in the system.

Comment: "Data delivered via Tap interface gets injected at layer2 of OSI..." - does delivered means "sent"?

Comment: "You are creating a VPN connection between two different hosts, so yes.." - does "yes" means the programs can run on different hosts?

Comment: "To do so you capture those packets..." - do you mean that some software capture the packets sent by the tap/tun interface?